# Get object's orientation or angle after object detection

Tags: neural-networks, ai-design, object-detection, object-recognition, yolo

I'm trying to get a detected car's orientation when object detection is applied. For instance, when we apply object detection on a car and get a bounding box, is there any ways or methods to calculate where the heading is or the orientation or direction of the car (just 2D plane is fine)?

Any thoughts or ideas would be helpful.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem can be phrased (more generally) as a *Pose Estimation Problem*.  That term might help in obtaining better search results when searching for relevant papers.

One paper that I found on the given topic was this [one](https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.04363). Even if it is maybe (for whatever reason) not what you are looking for precisely, it might still contain valuable references to different techniques that might be applicable to your problem at hand.

Answer (score 1):

There is a paper [face pose estimation](https://github.com/natanielruiz/deep-head-pose)

It uses a very straight forward technique, and very obvious augmentaions to achieve nice results.

You could use exactly the same if you have a tagged dataset for cars rather than for faces.

I was able to reproduce the results myself a while back.